# Android: Hide View when ListView is scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Here is the deal guys, I have an activity that contains 2 fragments (lets call them `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`). `FragmentA` layout contains a `ListView` and `FragmentB` layout has a `LinearLayout` which contains 3 `ImageButtons`.

What I am trying to do is to hide/make invisible FragmentB's `LinearLayout` when FragmentA's `ListView` is scrolled.

**Here is my ListFragment code**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View body = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag, container, false);

        View button = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_frag,container,false);

        linear = (LinearLayout) button.findViewById(R.id.buttons)

        myStuff = (ListView) body.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        myStuff.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView v, int firstVisibleItem,
                                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int scrollState) {

                switch(scrollState) {
                    case 2: // SCROLL_STATE_FLING
                        //hide button here
                        linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;

                    case 1: // SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL
                        //hide button here
                        linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;

                    case 0: // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
                        //show button here
                        linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;

                    default:
                        //show button here
                        linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

The code above is not working and since I am fairly new to Fragments I have hit a roadblock. Do you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is your code running? coz you have typo error here 'linear = (LinearLayout) button.findViewVyId(R.id.buttons)' ---- ById not VyId

Comment: @Saqib yes its running. I made the typo when I edited the code.

Comment: change code ...  linear = (LinearLayout) body.findViewVyId(R.id.buttons)